# Python naming conventions for functions that do modify the object or return a modified copy

Tags: python, naming-conventions, command-query-separation

What would be the naming conventions in Python for functions that can return a modified object or that just modifies the instance.

Let's assume you want to implement both, how you should name the functions?

Example: Let's assume that you want a `crop()` function for an Image object. I Ruby it was simple because you should use `crop()` if you return a copy and `crop!()` if you modify the original instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if there is a precise guideline in some PEP, but looking at how certain functions/method work in python core I personally use **verb conjugation**. For example, inspired by:

```
>>> l = list('hello world')
>>> l
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> sorted(l)
[' ', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'w']
>>> l
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
[' ', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'r', 'w']
```

I would name your functions `crop()` [modify object in place] and `cropped()` [return a modified copy].

**EDIT:** I don't know ruby, but in python the distinction between the two is purely conventional (function / method behaviour is independent from how you call it).

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

There are no "Python-wide" conventions for this AFAIK. However, a project I work on has a convention that may be useful to you: if a function can modify its argument in-place, it has a `copy` kwarg that determines whether it operates on a copy of its input, and defaults to `True`.

```
def crop(x, copy=True):
    if copy:
        x = x.copy()
    _do_inplace_crop(x)
    return x
```

Answer (score 2):

In the standard library, there are methods like `list.sort()` and `list.reverse()` which modify the `list` in place, and functions like `sorted()` and `reversed()` which return something new (`reversed()` returns an iterator rather than a new list). But if it makes more sense to have an instance method than a function, I wouldn't do this just to keep this convention.

In NumPy, many functions and methods have an `out` keyword argument that allow you to specify that the output should go to an existing array rather than creating a new one. You can even make the `out` array one of the input arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I want something to be modifiable in place, I would write a method:

```
smth.crop()
```

And if I would like it to return a modified object, then I would use a function:

```
crop(smth)
```

That way you keep functions in functional style (no side effects), and methods in OOP style (with side effects).

However, I also wish Python allowed `!` and `?` characters in function names like Ruby and Lisp.

Comment: As for `?`, there is a common convention for predicates--use `is` at the beginning of the function name.